# how to make terraform error when data is empty

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have problem with terraform especially with google load balancer `backend_service`

here's my sample tf config

```
var backends {
  default = [
     {
      'name':'red'
      'service': 'abcd'
     },
     {
      'name':'blue'
      'service': 'efgh'
     }
]
}

local {
backend = {for i in var.backends: "${i.name}-${i.service}" => i}
}

data "external" "mydata" {
    for_each = local.backend
    program = ["/bin/sh", "script.sh", each.value.name]
}
//that script will get some data like this //

{"id": "sometext"}

//

resource "google_compute_backend_service" "default" {
  project  = local.project_id
  for_each = local.backend
  name     = each.key

  dynamic "backend" {
    for_each = {for zone in var.zone: zone => "projects/${local.project_id}/zones/${zone}/networkEndpointGroups/${data.external.mydata[each.key].result.id}"}

  }
}
```

the problem is, if `data.external.mydata[each.key].result.id` is empty,the `terraform plan` is success/without error.
I want `terraform plan` to be error/failed in especially in `google_compute_backend_service`.

> here's sample external.data if empty
>
> {"id":""}

I want this to be error/failed in especially in `google_compute_backend_service`.

is it posible to reproduce error?
I know it can use `count` for checking the `external.data` value, but since I use `for_each`, so I cannot use `count`

Comment: You still can check the count with for_each. I'm not sure what the actual issue is?

Comment: it will error if i use count and for_each at same resource..
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html
my actual issue, is terraform plan is success when data.external.result.id  is empty..
i want it to be failed/error..

Comment: What do you want to do? Skip creation of `google_compute_backend_service` if `external.data` is empty? If so what is `local.backend`?

Comment: I update my question with local.backend..
i don't want to skip creation of `google_compute_backend_service` i want it reproduce error in terraform plan, when `external.data.id` is empty

Comment: because i use it in pipeline, when user create MR, and pipeline did `terraform plan` it show success.. but since `external.data.id` is empty, it will be failed/error when apply, because `google_compute_backend_service` doesn't found the self-link

Comment: You need to rewrite your external data to return some empty/null data when it likewise retrieves no data. Then Terraform would error as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the expected protocol for programs you execute with the `external` data source is that they can indicate an error by printing an error message to stderr and then exiting with a non-zero exit status.

In a shell script you could do that via some commands like the following:

```
echo >&2 "No matching object is available."
exit 1
```

If your command exits unsuccessfully like this then the `external` provider will detect that and return a failure, which will then in turn prevent Terraform from processing any resources that depend on that result.